# How To stop a user from type something in textbox with JS?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm practicing JS and I have a question from javascript.

I'm gonna make the user to type only letters and if the user decides to type numbers too, the program stop him/her. and please no jQuery Answers cuz I don't know anything about it yet.

here's my code......

```js
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function vent (t)
{
 var m=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/
  t=document.getElementById("txt");
 if(t.value.match(m))
 {
  alert("Co");
  return true;
 }
     
 else
 {
  // I want to write my preventing code here.......
 }
}
</script>
</head>
```

```html
<body>
<input type="text" id="txt" onBlur="vent (this)"/><br/>
<input type="text"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if input is number or letter javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042133/check-if-input-is-number-or-letter-javascript)

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556533/how-do-i-make-an-input-field-accept-only-letters-in-javascript

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When restricting user input to a subset of key values you would typically use the `onkeydown` event rather than blur.  That way you can prevent the user's keystroke from being added to the input value rather than trying to remove it after the fact.  All you need to do is cancel the event,  using `preventDefault()` or returning false from the keydown handler.  Note for older browsers you may need to check for `keyCode` in addition to `which`, i.e., `var c = e.which || e.keyCode;` then check the value of `c` against the allowed range.

```js
function allowOnlyCharacters(e)
{
    return e.which == 16 || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90);
}

var element = document.getElementById('txt');
element.onkeydown = allowOnlyCharacters;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt"/><br/>
<input type="text"/>
```