# What would be the best way to ignore characters in a input

Tags: javascript

If I give a input like `he7ck`
and I want it to ignore anything that isn't letters so it just takes the input as `heck` how would I do that?

Comment: Define "it just takes" in more precise terms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove not alphanumeric characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364400/remove-not-alphanumeric-characters-from-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make an input field accept only letters in javaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556533/how-do-i-make-an-input-field-accept-only-letters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```js
input.oninput = (e) => e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^a-z\s]+/gi, "");
```

```html
<input id="input"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple expression as follows:

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input",function(){
     var str = this.value;
     this.value = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]+/g, "")
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it was asked in the question or not but this doesn't support spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to replace everything that you do not want with nothing `""`. If you want it to entirely disallow users from entering numbers during input, keep it as it is. Otherwise, if you wanted it to get their full input then apply the restrictions, change the `input.oninput` function to `input.onchange`

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.oninput = function() {
  let data = this.value;
  if (data.match(/[0-9]/g)) {
     console.log(data);
     data = data.replace(/[0-9]/g, "");
     this.value = data;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="input">
```