# How do I only allow the user to type alpha characters in HTML text input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, input

I have a text input that I need to only accept 1 A-Z letter (not case sensitive). I am able to restrict the input to 1 character by using `maxlength`, but you can still type a number or special character in the input.

```
<input type="text" name="letter-1" maxlength="1" class="letter-input">
```

What can I do to restrict this input to only A-Z letters? It would be awesome if we can just do this in HTML, but I know we probably need JS. Would prefer to handle with Vanilla JS if possible. Also, as context, I have a bunch of these inputs and it would be nice if I can handle them all at once with a loop or something.

I know I can use `pattern`, but that only works to restrict the input on submitting the form. I do not want the user to even be able to type a number in the field, only alpha characters. If they try to type a number or special character, nothing should happen.

Comment: Use a JavaScript `input` listener that removes any non-alpha characters.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code to get me started?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556533/how-do-i-make-an-input-field-accept-only-letters-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

There are a million ways you could get here, but here's one...

```js
function lettersOnly(input) {
  // Remove any characters that are not letters
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input name="letter-1" maxlength="1" class="letter-input" oninput="lettersOnly(this)">
```

Comment: I think the `input` event works better here.

Comment: why not using the `pattern` attribute instead of js?